# Properly restricting Record in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to declare a generic TypeScript function that accepts a `Record<number, boolean>` and returns the same value.
I need the input type to be a generic type parameter, that is reflected in the output.
Unfortunately, calling the function, I don't get an error, when passing something [other than a number (`string`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) as the record key:

```js
const func = <T extends Record<number, boolean>>(input: T): T => input;

const x = func({
    1: true,
    test: false // <-- doesn't show error
})
```

It works if I inline the type `Record<number, boolean>`, but then I'm not able to use it in my return type:

```js
const func2 = (input: Record<number, boolean>): Record<number, boolean> => input;

const y = func2({
    1: true,
    test: false // <-- shows error
});
// ^? y: Record<number, boolean> - and not { 1: true }
```

How can I constrain my types, so I get errors for the input, but also preserve the output type?

**Disclaimer:** this is a simplified example. In the real code, more generic parameters exist and `T` is used in multiple places, one of them being a more complicated return type based on T.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Abw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You probably know this, but just in case: `Record` is a type abstraction for objects. Object property keys are never numbers, they're always strings or symbols. You can specify string properties in an object literal using both string literals and number literals, it's purely a convenience syntax -- the numbers are converted to strings. `{1: true}` and `{"1": true}` create identical objects, which have the string property name `"1"`. If you really want numbers as keys, you might consider a `Map` rather than an object.

Comment: (So why does TypeScript allow `number` as an object property key type? Probably because it's pragmatically useful when dealing with array types, which *per specification* have element properties with string keys [yes, really] but are implemented by JavaScript engines with actual arrays behind the scenes where possible/appropriate. But I don't know for sure that that's the reason, it's just a reasonable guess.)

Comment: @jcalz It's not quite there. The result now becomes `{ 1: boolean }` and not `{ 1: true }`. My problem is that I use a more complex type than `boolean` (`ZodRawShape` from Zod), and I need to be able to use that type later, when I map using the numerical keys.

Comment: So then [does this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4azXw) work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Oh, I've figured it out - and then I saw your reply :D It actually only needs a [`const` in the type to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeUlYBUYCmAHlAWACYQwDeMA2gNIwCWYMA1gQJ4hwy4BdAFwwmxUhSpgEAWwBGBAE4wA-DDkgQAGwIBDNiLAEAbkpgBfAHwAKVgAcEUEbgCUztJZZgHUANwAof2xoGCI0eCRga1oARhEoRQQCABoYACYROF0tCAILFwCAekKYUpgAPRVA4NgucMRkaJg4mASk1NJoTOzc-KKSssr-IA). What tricked me was leaving the wrong value in the definition, which caused the resulting type to look weird.

Comment: So shall I write up my original thing as an answer or the new version or what?

Comment: Yeah, please write an answer. I would say the version I posted in my last comment, since it's the most compact combination of your first and second solution.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible and not sealed/closed/"exact". If you have a type [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) like `T extends U`, it is quite possible for `T` to have more keys in it than are mentioned in `U`.  There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) requesting "exact" types, so that presumably `T extends Exact<U>` would prohibit `T` from having any extra keys in it, but for now it's not part of the language.

So instead of `T extends Record<number, boolean>`, which requires that all numeric keys have `boolean` values, but which says nothing whatsoever about non-numeric keys, you could make a recursive constraint like this:

```
 const func = 
   <const T extends { [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? boolean : never }>(
     input: T
   ): T => input;
```

Essentially `T` is constrained to a version of itself where all numeric keys have property values of type `boolean`, while all other keys have property values of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type). This will result in an error where you want it:

```
const y = func({ 1: true, test: false }); // error!
// ---------------------> ~~~~
// Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Oh and since you apparently care about the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `boolean` properties, you can make `T` [a `const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) as shown above, which (if you have no errors to mess things up), will preserve such information:

```
const x = func({ 1: true, 2: false });
/* const x: {
    readonly 1: true;
    readonly 2: false;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeUlYBUYCmAHlAWACYQwDeMA2gNIwCWYMA1gQJ4hwy4BdAFwwmxUhSpgEAWwBGBAE4wA-DDkgQAGwIBDNiLAEAbkpgBfAHwAKVgAcEUEbgCUztJZZgHUANwAof2xoGCI0eCRga1oARhEoRQQCABoYACYROF0tCAILFwCAegAqGGDYIhFqfxhamEU9cnAtLhg4mASkgLr6xubWjPhs3IDzGGLCnoA9FUDymFb0RGRotvjElI6CaEzhvPMCmELJpUUQRQBCf2OYAFp7h8en588AP3fX68ncLjs8gHINNo9GB-iwpCBYLoIBBmABzMC6OQ6DogDq-AFGUyKf4AOmsaQAzGk0i5-EA)